# Dual boot with mouse support on OS selection

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, keyboard

I have dual booted in the past, so I am quite clued up with installation and using Grub2. I have an issue with my keyboard not registering on anything before the operating system, that is, it will not work in BIOS, only my mouse, and I cannot choose which OS to boot into via Grub2. The keyboard that I am using is a Genius Imperator. Is there an implementation that will accept mouse input, as in a GUI of sort for OS selection?

Answer (score 0):

There is a grubmouse project that lets you partially use your mouse in grub menu. I tried it but couldn't manage to use it. If you want to give it a shot, here is the project:

https://bitbucket.org/byteit101/grub-mouse

Good luck!

Note: I don't  accept any responsibility from breakage of your system. I had to reinstall grub when I tried it.

Note 2: You can check out my previous posts to recover grub

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot and report back on how it goes.

Comment: Your keyboard needs drivers, and there is no support in Linux for Genius Imperator and a few other keyboards similar to yours. There are some patches that could make it work but it is a long shot, and some patches need kernel >=3.9 . Can't you just use some other keyboard each time you want to run Ubuntu? You know, keep your Genius Imperator, and plugin some USB or PS2 keyboard...